# Ubuntu installation freezes with ASUS (windows 10 dual boot)

Tags: boot, system-installation, windows, 15.10, freeze

I tried to boot up with from a CD and or USB with 15.10 Ubuntu iso. Eveytime I get the same result: "Install Ubuntu" => Loading (purple screen) and freeze.
I've disable CMS, and Fast Boot, and Secure mode boot in the BIOS. Update the BIOS, but none of these work.

Thank you in advance.

Tim

Answer (score 0):

Start Ubuntu into safe mode (Recovery Mode). Menu will appear with either *ESC* or *TAB* key. 
Check for the message where it gets stuck and reply back.